# Ghostscript ERROR: /undefined in --get--

Tags: pdf, centos, postscript, ghostscript

I'm trying to use Ghostscript in CentOS. When trying to issue the following Ghostscript command `ghostscript -sDEVICE=pcx256 -r150x150 -sOutputFile=OUTPUT_FILE INPUT_PDF` I am getting the following error:

> ESP Ghostscript 815.02 (2006-04-19)
>   Copyright (C) 2004 artofcode LLC,
>   Benicia, CA.  All rights reserved.
>   This software comes with NO WARRANTY:
>   see the file PUBLIC for details.
>   Processing pages 1 through 1. Page 1
>   ERROR: /undefined in --get-- Operand
>   stack:    --dict:8/8(L)--
>   --dict:8/11(L)--   CS0   --dict:10/10(ro)(G)--   CS0 Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop
>   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--
>   false   1   %stopped_push
>   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:    --dict:1121/1686(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:104/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:241/347(ro)(G)--   --dict:20/24(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:21/32(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:3/5(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:8/11(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last
>   OS error: 2 ESP Ghostscript 815.02:
>   Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Any help is supper appreciated! I've been Googling all weekend for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I had an older version running and I assumed that yum would automatically get the latest n greatest. Removed old version, installed the most current version by building and installing from source. Done.